# cron in docker isn't working but cron job shows when doing crontab -l

Tags: docker, flask, cron

I'm trying to have a cron job that calls for an endpoint of my flask application every minute. After building and running the image, I can see the job if I run `crontab -l` but my flask isn't reporting any call. Any idea why? any help is appreciated! Here's the setup

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron curl
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 13800
RUN chmod -v +x start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

here's what's inside start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/crontab periodicGossipInvoker
# start cron
service cron start
# Flask
python main.py
```

here's what's inside periodicGossipInvoker:

```
* * * * * sleep 10; /usr/bin/curl http://0.0.0.0:13800/dict
```

here's the run:

```
$ docker run --name="node1"        --net=kv_subnet     \
>            --ip=10.10.0.2        -p 13802:13800      \
>            -e ADDRESS="${addr1}"                     \
>            -e VIEW=${initial_full_view}              \
>            -e REPL_FACTOR=2                          \
>            kv-store:4.0
Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:13800/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 104-728-720
```

The problem is, the flask app never gets any call from the cron job, even though I see the cron job when I do

```
docker exec -ti 556 crontab -l
* * * * * sleep 10; /usr/bin/curl http://0.0.0.0:13800/dict
```

Comment: I am not familiar with docker or flask; but shouldn't you do something like: `/usr/bin/curl http://0.0.0.0:13800/dict > /my/home/dir/output-file`

Comment: @Roadowl yes I'd do that if there's no way to monitor incoming request with flask, however since flask shows something like `127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2019 20:08:11] "GET /dict HTTP/1.1" 200 -` when getting a request (I've tested it by doing `docker exec -ti 556 /usr/bin/curl http://0.0.0.0:13800/dict`) I skipped that step. appreciate the help though!

Comment: What about this: `sleep 10 && /usr/bin/curl http://0.0.0.0:13800/dict`.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't a valid IP address within the curl command.  The request should be `/usr/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1/dict` if the app is running in the same container as the cron daemon.  However this is breaks the 1-process-per-container rule.  Really the cron part should run in one container and the flask app in another.

Comment: @Roadowl just tried it, also tried to just take out sleep, but both with no luck

Comment: @v25 interesting, I'd not have considered that since I did ```docker exec -ti 556 /usr/bin/curl http://0.0.0.0:13800/dict``` and it worked. anyway I tried changing the one in cronjob to ```http://127.0.0.1:13800/dict``` but with no luck. Yeah having 2 containers would be the ideal setup except this is for a school assignment, so I have no control over how many docker containers I can run. maybe I should look for alternatives for cron that works with flask. Thanks regardless!